# prove or disprove for $|x|<1$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$ $\left| \frac{x^n}{1-x} \right | \leq \frac{1}{n} $

Tags: real-analysis

prove or disprove for $|x|<1$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$
             $$\left| \frac{x^n}{1-x} \right | \leq  \frac{1}{n} $$

---

I want it to be true but can't get it here is my attempt
let $|x|=\left |\frac{1}{1+t} \right|$  and using Binomial theorem
$$\begin{aligned} (1+t)^n
   &= \sum^{n}_{k=0} \binom{n}{k} 1^k t^{n-k}
\\  &= \binom{n}{0} 1^0 t^{n-0}  + \binom{n}{1} 1^1 t^{n-1} 
        +\dots +\binom{n}{n-1} 1^k t^{n-(n-1)}+\binom{n}{n} 1^k t^{n-n}
\\&=1t^n + \frac{n!}{1!(n-1)! }
t^{n-1} +\dots + \frac{n!}{(n-1)!1!} t^1+1
\\ &=t^n+nt^{n-1}+\dots +nt+1
\end{aligned}$$
so

$$ \begin{aligned} 
\left | \frac{x^n}{1-x} \right |
&=\left | \left (\frac{1}{1+t}\right )^n \left ( \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{1-t}} \right)\right |
\\&= \left | \frac{1}{\left (1+t \right)^n} \left ( \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{1-t}} \right)\right |
\\&= \left | \frac{1}{t^n+nt^{n-1}+\dots +nt+1} \left ( \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{1-t}} \right)\right |
\\& \leq  \left | \frac{1}{nt+1} \left ( \frac{1}{\frac{1}{1-t}} \right)\right |=\frac{1+t}{nt+1}=\frac{1+t}{n(t+1/n)}\leq \frac{1+t}{nt}
\\&=\frac{1/t+1}{n}
\end{aligned}
$$
but on the other hand as $x \to 1$ or $t \to 0$then it might not hold 
this is related to [previous problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1807592/epsilon-delta-proof-of-geometric-series-x1) I asked because if that holds might be able to say that it converges uniformly because it dosent depend on the value of x.

---

Comment: How can this be true for any $n$, the LHS goes to infinity ?

Comment: yeah n goes to infinity forgot to mention that !!!

Comment: For any $n$ you can falsify the inequality for some $x$'s, there's no uniform convergence.

Comment: $x^n/(1-x) \to \infty$ as $x\to 1^-,$ so there's no hope of any bound by a constant, much less the bound of $1/n.$